# Parsed strings sometimes becomes 0

Tags: go

I have a problem when parsing from a string to an integer that sometimes the string is being parsed to 0, despite not being 0.

*Example:*

What I would like to do first is parsing a string into three different integers. My code looks as follows:

```
package main
import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "strconv"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
    line, _ := reader.ReadString('\n')

    splitted := strings.Split(line, " ")

    N, _ := strconv.ParseInt(splitted[0], 0, 64) //Works as intended
    P, _ := strconv.ParseInt(splitted[1], 0, 64) //Works as intended
    Q, _ := strconv.ParseInt(splitted[2], 0, 64) //Does not work as intended

    fmt.Print(N, P, Q)  //For testing the parsing

}
```

If I input the string: "5 25 125", the output somehow becomes: 
5 25 0.

This is the problem, sometimes the parsing parses the integer to the content of the string, which it should. But sometimes it parses the integer into a zero.

Why is this?

Comment: Have you checked whether the function returns an error?

Comment: Please provide a runnable link.

Answer (score 3):

> [ReadString](https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#Reader.ReadString) reads
>   until the first occurrence of delim in the input, returning a string
>   containing the data up to and including the delimiter.

So `splitted[2]` is `125\n`, you should check the error in `strconv.ParseInt(splitted[2], 0, 64)`, it's not `nil` so that the returned value is 0.

Comment: You could do `splitted := strings.Split(line[:len(line)-1], " ")` to get rid of the last character.